# How to translate this css animation to jQuery

Tags: jquery, css, animation

Basically the css animation would turn all divs to 0 opacity and only 1 to 1 every 4 seconds. It's a simple slider principle, although there isn't much sliding going on. I'd appreciate the help since i'm a complete jQuery newbie. And everything you believe is a given is yet unexplored land to me, so if there is any details even the most obvious one of all, feel free to add it.

PS: There is a million thing wrong with my script and and not to mention that it can only work with only 2 slides.. So please focus more on my description

```
.div1-1, .div-2{
width:100%;
height:100%;
position:absolute;
}
.div-1{
animation:first 4s 0 infinite;
}
.div-2{
animation:second 4s 4s infinite;
}

@keyrames first{
from(opacity:1);
to(opacity:0);
}
@keyrames second{
from(opacity:1);
to(opacity:0);
}
```

Comment: What have you tried?  It appears you are simply asking us to write code for you. This website was not intended to have questions like this.  I'd suggest visiting the jQuery website's documentation for the method [`css()`](http://api.jquery.com/css/) for starters.

Answer (score 0):

to be honest, you description is not what you call descriptive, however, if I'm not mistaken, what you need is `fade()` so given your div tags have id's assigned to them you can use `$("#yourDivID").fadeOut(500)` which will fade your div tag out in 500 ms. here is a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/fyx2w9ym/) that displays the above.

Comment: That's close to what i'm looking for, but how can i use this to create an actual slider? all divs should be hidden and one at a time they all fade in

Comment: you need to select all of your divs at the same time. so in your jQuery selector e.g. instead of  $("#yourDivID") use $("someUniqueClass") and your divs should all have that class.

Comment: A fiddle would be nice if you can, and i'm very sorry, i know i already took enough of your time!